# Content Slider in jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, slider

I have created the slider in jQuery script but it does not work properly. The slider are not return to the first content when goes to another page.

HTML:

```
<div class="note_slider1" style="z-index: 100; position:absolute; left: 82px; top: 250px; width: 687px; height: 270px;">
    <div class="slider_close" style="position:absolute; left: 548px; top: 4px;"></div>
    <div class="slider_title" id="title" style="position:absolute; left: 61px; height: 22px; top: 4px; width: 319px;">Title: Electronic Enterprise</div>
    <div id="page">
        <ul id="slider1" class="slider">
            <li style="font-size:14px">aaaaa</li>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>test test123</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="note_slider2" style="z-index: 100; position:absolute; left: 82px; top: 250px; width: 687px; height: 270px;">
    <div class="slider_close" style="position:absolute; left: 549px; top: 4px;"></div>
    <div class="slider_title" id="title" style="position:absolute; left: 61px; height: 22px; top: 4px; width: 319px;">Title: Electronic Enterprise 123</div>
    <div id="page">
        <ul id="slider2" class="slider">
            <li>test test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then there are the code for plugin with rhinoslider:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').rhinoslider({
        showBullets: 'never',
        //showControls: 'always'
    });
    $('#slider2').rhinoslider({
        showBullets: 'never',
        controlsPrevNext: false,
        //showControls: 'always'
    });
    $('#slider3').rhinoslider({
        showBullets: 'never',
        //showControls: 'always'
    });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle or full html code needed.